# onclick function won't work after onchange for id

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i give my input in the beginning an id, then my button works just fine with an onclick function. But if i assign an id to my button with an onchange function my button won't react to the onclickfunction while the id is correct. Can anyone help me with this.

This works:

```
 <input type="button" class="ok" value="Execute" id="mercedes"/>
 <script>
 $('#mercedes').on('click', function(e){
 ......
 </script>
```

This doesn't work:

```
 <select id="abc" onchange="func()">
   <option  value="volvo" id="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab" id="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes" id="3">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi" id="4">Audi</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" class="ok" value="Execute"/>
 <script>
     function func() {
         var b = document.getElementById("abc");
         var a= b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
         $('input.ok').attr('id', a);
      }
 </script>
 <script>
 $('#mercedes').on('click', function(e){
 ......
 </script>
```

When I select mercedes from the options my input will get the id mercedes, but the onclick function still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to be an XY problem. **Why are you changing the `id` anyway?** What is your use-case? Apart from that the real reason is that when you are using the selector to bind the click event it is bound using that selector which is later on changed by you. Cache the element before you start changing the `id`s. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/wch0e9e9/

Comment: Where do you execute func()? It isn't called at all.

Comment: It's an on change on the select field.

Comment: How would the button click work, if the selected id is not mercedes.

Comment: But you execute $('#mercedes').on('click', function(e) when the page loads. Of course it can't attach the listeners to the options because they have not the correct Ids yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mercedes').on('click', function(e){
```

This is happening when the page loads. The element does not have an id yet. Inside the on change you need to attach the event once the id is set.

```
function func() {
     var b = document.getElementById("abc");
     var a= b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
     $('input.ok').attr('id', a);
     $('#' + a).on('click', function(e){
          // do something
     });
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bt3dsrbx/